# Adding your own basic templates using MJML

Tags: email, templating, mjml

MJML looks great for what I want to use it for.

I want to create a set of templates so that it's much easier for my co-workers to build emails in the future. However, the 'basic' and 'gallery' sections don't have an option to be populated, can I create my own templates for these sections? It'd be nice to start a project without having to duplicate an existing one.

It'd be great if this is achievable without having to download the source code and rebuild it,

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Although not explicitly mentioned, I suppose you're referring to Mailjet's gallery of templates.

You cannot add your own templates to the default Mailjet gallery. However, it's easy to create your own templates that will then appear under "My templates".

To do so, simply create a template in drag and drop, import a MJML file (that you can edit with the MJML editor or in drag and drop), or import a HTML file.

Finally, if you need to share those templates:

- Inside the same Mailjet Master Account: you can share templates from a master account to each subaccount (see [doc](https://www.mailjet.com/support/can-i-give-or-share-access-to-my-account,466.htm))
- Between two Mailjet accounts that have nothing to do together: export the template as a MJML file and reimport it in the new account (you'll be able to edit it in MJML or drag-and-drop). See [doc](https://www.mailjet.com/docs/templates#templates-manage-export)